# Different color between line and area graph

Tags: d3.js

[edit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsGc1.png)
I am using d3 v4. In which I created area and line chart. data formation is.
Chart => [1,4,5,2.4,6]
line => [3,3,3,3,3]

Now my requirement is below the line chart, area graph should have a different color.

If there is any other library which can do this, then also suggest.
Here is my function to draw the line and area graph.
so if **dailyConsValue> targetConsValue ? 'no color' : 'show color'**
dailydate is year [Jan 2017 - dec 2017] => this is dynamically.

Below is my code:

```
function drawGraph(drawData, highlightedData, first, last) {
let margin, width, height, parseDate, xScale, yScale, area, 
dailyConsumption, targetConsumption, svg;
margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 60,
  bottom: 10,
  left: 60
},
width = document.querySelector('#graph').clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = document.querySelector('#graph').clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

parseDate = d3.timeParse('%b %Y');
// x axis
xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([parseDate(first), parseDate(last)]).range([0, width]);
// y axis
yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-1, 2 + Math.max.apply(this, drawData.map(function(o){return o.dailyConsValue; }))])
.range([height, 0]);

area = d3.area()
.x(function(d) { return xScale(d['dailyDate']); })
.y0(function(d) { return yScale(d['targetConsValue']); })
.y1(function(d) { return yScale(d['dailyConsValue']); });
// define the line
dailyConsumption = d3.line().x(function(d) {return xScale(d['dailyDate']); })
 .y(function(d) {return yScale(d['dailyConsValue']); });

targetConsumption = d3.line().x(function(d) {return xScale(d['dailyDate']); })
    .y(function(d) {return yScale(d['targetConsValue']); });

svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform',
          'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

 // add axis
 svg.append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').attr('class', 'Xaxis')
 .call(d3.axisTop(xScale).ticks(drawData.length).tickSize(-innerHeight).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %Y')));
 svg.append('g').attr('class', 'Yaxis')
 .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0));

 // Prepare data
 drawData.forEach(function( d ) {
   d['dailyDate'] = parseDate( d['dailyDate'] );
   d['targetConsValue'] = d['targetConsValue'];
   d['dailyConsValue'] = d['dailyConsValue'];
 } );

 highlightedData.forEach(function( d ) {
   d['dailyDate'] = parseDate( d['dailyDate'] );
   d['dailyConsValue'] = d['dailyConsValue'];
   d['active'] = d['active'];
 } );

 // add the area
 svg.append('path').data([drawData]).attr('class', 'area')
 .attr('d', area)
  .transition().duration(2500).attrTween( 'd', this.tween( drawData, area ) );

 // add data for first line
 svg.append('path')
 .data([drawData])
 .attr('class', 'daily').attr('d', targetConsumption).transition()
 .duration(2500).delay(1500 / 2).attrTween( 'd', this.tween( drawData, targetConsumption ) );

// add data for futureConsumption
 svg.append('path')
 .data([drawData])
 .attr('class', 'target').attr('data-legend', 'CST')
 .attr('d', dailyConsumption);

 createLengends(drawData);
 drawCircle(drawData, '10', '#037DA6');
 drawCircle(drawData, '5', '#003A54');


/**
 * legends start
 * @param datalegendsData
 */
function createLengends(datalegendsData) {
  let legend;
  legend = svg.selectAll('.legend').data([datalegendsData])
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) { return 'translate(0,' + i * 20 + ')'; });
  // making a line for legend
  legend.append('line')
      .attr('x1', width - 335).attr('x2', width - 305).attr('y1', height - 1)
      .attr('y2', height - 1).style('stroke', '5,5').style('stroke', '#4682B4');

  legend.append('text').attr('x', width - 300).attr('y', height - 1)
      .attr('dy', '.35em').style('text-anchor', 'start').text('IST Verbrauch WOB')
      .style('fill', '#666').style('font-weight', 'normal');

  legend.append('line').attr('x1', width - 130).attr('x2', width - 100)
      .attr('y1', height - 1).attr('y2', height - 1).style('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
      .style('stroke', '#003A54');

  legend.append('text').attr('x', width - 96).attr('y', height - 1).attr('dy', '.35em')
      .style('text-anchor', 'start').text('CST Sollwert').style('fill', '#666')
      .style('font-weight', 'normal');
}
// legends end

/**
 * highlighted data points start
 * @param data
 * @param r
 * @param color
 */
function drawCircle(data, r, color) {
  let tooltip;
  tooltip = d3.select('#graph').append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip').style('display', 'none');
  svg.selectAll('.dot').data(data).enter().append('circle') // Uses the enter().append() method
  .attr('class', 'circle_' + r).attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d['dailyDate']); })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {return yScale(d['dailyConsValue']); }).attr('r', r).attr('fill', color)
    .on( 'mouseover', function( d) {
      let arr, date;
      d3.select( this ).classed('circle circle__highlighted', true);
      d['active'] = true;
      tooltip.transition().duration(200).style('display', 'block');
      arr = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
      date = arr[d['dailyDate'].getMonth()] + ', ' + d['dailyDate'].getFullYear();
      tooltip.html('Month ' + date + '<br/> Consumption- ' + d['dailyConsValue'] + ' unit')
      .style('left', (parseInt(this.getAttribute('cx'), 10) + 70) + 'px').style('top', (this.getAttribute('cy')) + 'px');
      /*tooltip.html('Month ' + date + '<br/> Consumption- ' + d['dailyConsValue'] + ' unit')
        .style('left', (d3.event.offsetX + 20) + 'px').style('top', (d3.event.offsetY - 28) + 'px');*/
  } ).on( 'mouseout', function( d ) {
        d3.selectAll('.circle').classed('circle', true).classed('circle__highlighted', false);
        d['active'] = false;
        tooltip.transition().duration(500).style('display', 'none');
  } );
}
// highlighted data points end
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more code. Color change is definitely possible.

Comment: Assign an ID or class to the line and area and use "stroke" or "fill" using css or by using ".style('fill','#cc0000')"

Comment: I gave that but it fill entire area graph. Which I donot want.

Comment: Then how do you want to color your area chart?

Comment: When I am filling the data then i have to check if my dailyConsValue<targetConsValue then I have to fill the value.

Comment: So you want a gradient for the area fill?

Comment: NO.. I want green color and if greater than blue

Comment: Can you please post the full data or the at least the structure of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `style fill` just create a function and compare the two values and return a color based on the condition like so:

```
svg.append('path')
   .data([drawData]).attr('class', 'area')
   .attr('d', area)
   .style('fill', function(d){
      for (i in d) {
        if (d[i]['dailyConsValue'] < d[i]['targetConsValue']) {
           return "green"
        } else {
           return "blue"
        }
   }
   })
   .transition().duration(2500)
   .attrTween( 'd', this.tween( drawData, area ) );
```

This will work based on only the last value of the data. If you want different colors at every point of the chart depending on your condition, you will have to create a `linearGradient` with multiple color stops (dynamically) as far as I know.

Now to create a `linearGradient`, I have created a linear scale using d3 to calculate the offset for color stops and assign color based on your condition. To dynamically create a `linearGradient` refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aditya_kk29/gsy5dt8h/)

https://jsfiddle.net/aditya_kk29/gsy5dt8h/

Comment: it is not working because d will be [{dailyConsValue: 2,targetConsValue:3 }, {dailyConsValue: 4,targetConsValue:3} , {dailyConsValue: 2.5,targetConsValue:3}] and return array of color

Comment: @Himani I'm not able to understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you please post a picture of what you want your area chart to look like?

Comment: Hey Aditya, here is the link and also i attached the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsGc1.png

Comment: @Himani That is actually a gradient but with hard color stops; meaning there is no gradual change of color in the gradient. You can either have one solid color or dynamically generate color stops (not easy for a beginner) because your area chart is just one path element. I suggest you read a little about linearGradients.

Comment: @Himani Please have a look at the fiddle above and try to figure out how it works.

Comment: Okay. But my target consumption i.e. a straight line may change to another form. So in that case my gradient cannot be give fixed form like 40 or 50 %. I used that.

Comment: @Himani Please check out the fiddle. I have dynamically created the gradient.

Comment: Hi, It worked to somewhat extent. But If line graph changes it form meaning will not be straight line then it does not reflect the similar result.